# In Julia, if date is 96, how can I make it 1996 in DateTime?

Tags: date, datetime, types, format, julia

I have an array with strings of dates. The format is "2/27/16 3:47" so "m-d-y H:M". However, DateTime parses this as `0016-27-02T03:47:00`. I would like to have the output be: `2016-27-2T03:47:00`.

My code is:

`map(date-> DateTime(date, "mm/dd/yy HH:MM"), datsub[:date])`

Side question: The output type becomes `Any`. Is this the correct type or should it be `DateTime` or something similar?

Comment: Perhaps `Dates.Year(2000) + DateTime(date, "mm/dd/yy HH:MM")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @akrun mentioned, you should add the year yourself:

```
Dates.Year(2000) + DateTime(date, "m/d/y H:M")
```

This is more explicit about exactly what is happening. Otherwise Dates would have to guess what exactly something like 97 means: 1997 or 2097, or actually year [00]97?

It's possible that you might want to come up with a reasonable cutoff for what year to add. You can try the following:

```
expandyear(date::DateTime) = date + (Dates.year(date) < 25 ? Dates.Year(2000) : Dates.Year(1900))
```

with whatever cutoff you think makes sense.

The issue with return types with `map` is a known problem that has been fixed in the latest v0.5 nightlies. Julia v0.5 is likely to be released in the near future, perhaps within several months.

Comment: Thanks @Fengyang Wang and @akrun. Adding the `Dates.Year(2000)` was effective for my problem. I will come back to this if I need to use 1900 and 2000 dates together

Comment: @Nick If you feel like this answer solved your problem, then you should accept it. This will make the question show up as answered.

Comment: @niczky12 whoops. not sure how to do that. I clicked on the checkmark just now, is that all?

Comment: @Nick yep. Looks like you accepted the answer. Welcome to the community!